# Compare two objects of same class in an if statement

Tags: c++, object, compare

How can you use an if statement that can compare two different objects of the same class in C++? 
"currentAnimation" and "animationSet[0]" are both objects of "class animation"

```
void setAnimation()
{
        //If object 1 doesn't equal object 2...
        if (currentAnimation != animationSet[0])
        //Make object 1 it equal object 2.
            currentAnimation = animationSet[0]; 
}
```

This is the error:

```
IntelliSense: no operator "!=" matches these operands
operand types are: animation != animation
```

Is this what pointers are for?

Comment: Overload the `operator==` and `operator!=` functions for your class?

Comment: Okay sure, once I find out what that is lol thanks.

Comment: @KevinAnderson - The compiler has no idea how to compare types it knows nothing about or what are the rules that makes two of these types equal or not equal.  You have to help it by telling the compiler how to compare these types.  That is what `operator==` and `operator!=` are all about.  Also, don't post Intellisense errors.  Post compiler errors, the ones that start with `C`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This case can be the case pointers are for. For comparing objects with pointers you should change this code:

```
if (currentAnimation != animationSet[0])
```

to this:

```
if (&currentAnimation != &animationSet[0])
```

so you will be comparing addresses in memory and this code must compile. However this checks only addresses, not data storing in them. Comparing addresses suits if you want to check are you pointing at the same object or not. If you want to check data in different objects (is data the same?), you need to implement at least one of comparison operators for your class (comparison operators usually should be defined outside the class but be friends to it to have access to its private fields):

```
class animation
{
//your code
public:
    friend bool operator==(const animation & a1, const animation & a2);
    friend bool operator!=(const animation & a1, const animation & a2);
};
```

And definition:

```
bool operator==(const animation & a1, const animation & a2)
{
    //the case we are pointing to the same object
    if(&a1 == &a2)
        return true;

    //here some code that compare fields of a1 and a2 and decide wether they are equal or not
}

bool operator!=(const animation & a1, const animation & a2)
{
    //we can use already defined operator==(), for example
    return !(a1 == a2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the easy solution, I somehow managed to let that slip by, what I had at first was: currentAnimation != &animationSet[name] (currentAnimation is missing "&") and was getting an error, but now I'm like "Oh duh, of course that's an error!" Atleast now I learned a bit about overloading operators.

Comment: I hope you understand the drawbacks of this easy solution. If you have string s1 = "Hello world!" and s2 = "Hello world!", with overloading operator you will get s1 == s2 -> true, but with &s1 == &s2 -> false.

Comment: Yeah I'm currently thinking about that right now, animation sets should stay the same. They are just supposed to be set up or "initialized" so that whenever whenever I want to switch my creature's current animation set, I just duplicate all the properties of the wanted animation set to the creature's current animation set. It does give all the properties and does seem to work, but I think it would be safer to just pass the values, not the address.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler doesn't know to compare your objects since they are user defined data types. If you want to compare your objects you should have both `==` and `!=` operators overloaded.

Have a look at this link,

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

Comment: @KevinAnderson - Some advice -- first write `operator==`.  Then write `operator !=` by simply calling `!operator==()`.

Comment: Thanks, I get you ... I think. Im calling currentAnimation.operator!=(animationSet[name])